# Expectation conditioned with respect to filtration of stochastic time changed process union with stochastic time change process.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let the stochastic processes $M=(M_t,t\ge 0)$, $v=(v_t,t\ge 0)$ and $M_v=(M_{v_t},t\ge 0)$ be defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$.

Denote $\mathcal F_t^M$ $\mathcal F_t^v$ and $\mathcal F_t^{M_v}$ as their natural filtrations, respectively. Further denote $\mathcal F_t=\mathcal F_t^{M_v}\vee \mathcal F_t^v$.

Does the following

$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M(v_t)|\mathcal F_s\vee \mathcal F_t^v]|\mathcal F_s]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M(v_t)|\mathcal F^M_{v_s}\vee \mathcal F_t^v]|\mathcal F_s]$

hold?

If it does not hold in general, what if $v$ is a pathwise continuous increasing process independent of $M$? Will the above hold in this special case?